# How to import JavaScript file into a Stencil component?

Tags: javascript, stenciljs

What is the JavaScript equivalent to `styleUrl`?
For importing CSS, it's:

```
@Component({
  tag: 'my-random-component',
  styleUrl: '../../index.scss',
  shadow: true
})
```

What if I want to import JavaScript instead? I could not find anything about JavaScript in the Stencil documentation.

I have heard that JS is written inside `index.ts` file, and I did, but nothing happens. The function that I imported in my `index.ts` is not being invoked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `stencil.config.ts`, add:
`globalScript: 'src/index.ts'` below the `namespace`.

JS can be written inside `index.ts`.